# Why am I getting AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException error?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I have just started a new project and am trying to connect to Firebase.

As soon as I try to build my project I got the error:

> Could not parse the Android application Module's Gradle Config

So I looked in my build which told me that jCenter() was deprecated and that I should remove it. When I removed it, everything worked fine. However, when I tried to connect to Firebase I got the error:

> AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException.

**What may be causing this?**

Full stack trace:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.ExternalApiUsageException: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method setVariantDir() for arguments [debug] on task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' of type com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask.
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:71)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:54)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.AnalyticsResourceManager.recordBlockAtConfiguration(AnalyticsResourceManager.kt:206)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.AnalyticsConfiguratorService.recordBlock(AnalyticsConfiguratorService.kt:85)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$9(BasePlugin.java:582)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.CrashReporting$afterEvaluate$1.execute(crash_reporting.kt:37)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.CrashReporting$afterEvaluate$1.execute(crash_reporting.kt)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I came here because I am getting the same error. Luckily I was updating dependencies when it happened and narrowed it down to:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.6'
```

Change it to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
```

The error goes away for me. Hopefully for you too

Here is more info on my dependencies.

Running Android Studio 4.2 build April 28 2021

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.6.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.0'
```

Gradle Plugin 4.2.0
Gradle 7.0.1

```
//Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.0'
```

Comment: Wow, a matter of minutes. Same here, narrowed it down to that library.

Comment: it helped that the only thing I did to an existing project was update dependencies and the error happened. Made it easy to track down

Comment: You can follow the issue over here: https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/176

Comment: Correct, I also came across this issue while I was updating the dependencies. Luckily, I had just committed the code, so the only change was this library changed to version 4.3.6 from 4.3.5
Came here to see if anyone could make it work with the latest version.

Comment: Same with flutter, you can change `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:+'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'`

Comment: The issue is fixed, [Could not find setVariantDir after 4.3.6 #176](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/176#issuecomment-841421672). You can use `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'` or stick on `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'`

Comment: Confirmed! Downgrading to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5' got rid of the error.

Comment: Point to add. Using the in IDE firebase guide causes it to use 'classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.6'..

Comment: for me i remove .gradle non used version folder

Answer (score 17):

**Update :** Google has just fixed the problem in version `4.3.8` **([Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases))**

An updated version of the google-services plugin for Android (v4.3.8) is now available. For more information, see the [**Firebase Android SDK Release Notes**](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#google-services_plugin_v4-3-8).

---

The error came from classpath  **`'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.6'`**

#### The easiest solution :

Go back to version `4.3.5`

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
}
```

Instead of `4.3.6`

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.6'
}
```

> In fact, version `4.3.6` is responsible for this error. The easiest
> way is to go back to the previous version until it is fixed

Comment: I'm already on 4.3.10

Answer (score 7):

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.ExternalApiUsageException:
> org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException:
> Could not find method setVariantDir()

### Fixed bug

You should use the latest possible version.

**DO**

```
dependencies {
       
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8' 

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Addition to RRiven fix,
I started getting error Plugin with id ‘maven’ not found after RRiven fix.

I fixed it with downgrading gradle version to 6.9 from file -> project structure -> project -> gradle version

Answer (score 3):

Set Code in build.gradle(Project)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
```

Set Line in gradle-wrapper

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way. Google has resolved it.

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
```

Go to the latest version now of 4.3.8

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#google-services_plugin_v4-3-8

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#google-services_plugin_v4-3-8

Answer (score 0):

In **Kotlin**, Gradle version 7.3.3

1- **build.gradle (Project)**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false

}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

2- **build.gradle (Module)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}
```