# Is there a way to use Realtime Database which require google services 4.3.6 with the current problems?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, build.gradle

So first my problem is the same as listed here :
[Why am I getting AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67496084/why-am-i-getting-abstractdynamicobjectcustommessagemissingmethodexception-error)

The fix provided there was to downgrade our google service to an older version 4.3.5
But the problem is my Firebase Realtime Database require google services 4.3.6 so I was wondering if there was a way to make it work.

Thank you for reading !

Answer (score 0):

When I also upgraded google services 4.3.6, I had this error. I don't know how to make it work with 4.3.6, but if you want to use realtime database with 4.3.5 then, setup the realtime database dependency manually. And don't use the tools options to setup realtime database.
Put the given dependency in project level gradle file

```
    dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

}
```

And put the given dependency in app level gradle file

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.7.0'
```

And also don't forget to put your json file in project.

Comment: I tried but seems like it's not working,
Or maybe i'm just being dumb and my code ain't working,
But it's not saving data into my realtime database even tho i'm following tutorial.
Also my authentification is connected because the user is being added to it, but at the same time im trying to register a new object User, and add that new User object to the realtime database but nothing happen, I feel like there's no connection between my application and the realtime db