# Why im getting this error in adding dependency

Tags: android

[image]

whenever i tries to add firebase dependency of Authentication it show some

Gradle DSL method not found: 'setVariantDir()'     this error.

Comment: which dependency? add it where? post code, not screenshots of why your build is failing. which gradle version too? [mcve] please.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67496084/why-am-i-getting-abstractdynamicobjectcustommessagemissingmethodexception-error

Comment: Please post your gradle file ane gradle dependecies here.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the /build.gradle int his line classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5', the error for me, i was using 4.3.6 and then change it to 4.3.5 and try sync again

[image]

[image]